# css math functions backwards compatibility

Tags: css, google-chrome

When using the following css selector on a toolbar to require a minimum bottom margin, it causes the toolbar height to be 0 on Chrome 59:

```css
.toolbar {
   height: calc(var(--f7-toolbar-height) + max(var(--f7-safe-area-bottom), 10px));
}
```

I tried the following, hoping Chrome 59 would only use the first height definition:

```
  height: calc(var(--f7-toolbar-height) + var(--f7-safe-area-bottom));
  height: calc(var(--f7-toolbar-height) + max(var(--f7-safe-area-bottom), 10px));
```

But Chrome 59 still uses only the second height definition which results in 0 height.

The following also doesn't work:

```css
@supports(height: max(0px)) {
      height: calc(var(--f7-toolbar-height) + max(var(--f7-safe-area-bottom), 10px));
    }
```

It still tries to apply the height, and causes 0 height.

Is there a backwards compatible way to achieve this height? It would be fine if Chrome 59 simply ignored the height and inherit it from somewhere else, as long as it doesn't cause a 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works:

```css
&.supports-css-math {
      height: calc(var(--f7-toolbar-height) + max(var(--f7-safe-area-bottom), 10px));
    }
```

And then in javascript, that `supports-css-math` class needs to be added. If using react or vue, it can be added in the component's template.

Another approach that might be better, but haven't tried yet, would be to add the `supports-css-math` at the top of the dom, and then define a css variable based on the selector, e.g., `--min-toolbar-bottom`, which can later be used in the toolbar component.